# Getting ListView values into a string array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView control set up in details mode, and on a button press I would like to retrieve all column values from that row in the ListView.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim items As ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection = _
    Me.ManageList.SelectedItems
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    Dim values(0 To 4) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each item In items
        values(i) = item.SubItems(1).Text
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

But `values` just comes out as an empty array. Any ideas? I just want the `values` array to be filled with the data of that ListView row.

Cheers.

Comment: Are any values actually selected when before you click the button?

Comment: Yeah, I make sure I've selected something :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the single-line solution:

```
mylistview.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Select(Function(lvi As ListViewItem)lvi.SubItems(1).Text).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the SubItems, not the selected items.  Fix:

```
If Me.ManageList.Items.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim row As ListViewItem = Me.ManageList.Items(0)
Dim values(0 To row.SubItems.Count-1) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each item As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In row.SubItems
  values(i) = item.Text
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, are you aware that item.SubItems(1).Text will get the texts from the second column? And that since you're using SelectedItems it'll only look at the currently selected items in the ListView.

Edit: 
Also, are you sure there will always just be a maximum of 5 selected items in the ListView?
Otherwise you'll have problems with

```
Dim values(0 To 4) As String
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it's 0 based and looking at the selected items is what I want :)

Comment: Then I can't think of anyhting more since the code above works (for up to 5 selections).

Comment: You don't have any hidden (0 width) columns so that you might be reading the wrong one?

Comment: If I try: `MessageBox.Show(values(2))` or something the messagebox comes up with no text, making me think the array is empty. But yeah, the code does compile and run fine.

Comment: And nah I don't have any hidden columns.

Comment: Rather than using messagebox, put a breakpoint on the End Sub line and debug it and when it breaks you can move the mouse over the values variable and click on the little + sign to see all the values of it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know... maybe this helps for someones reference.. stumbled upon this question in a search for something else.

This works... not sure if the original poster somehow used an empy colelciton of selected items...

Also, dynamically resizing array based on selected items to overcome unforseen bugs...

```
    Dim valueArray(mylistview.SelectedItems.Count - 1) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each Item As ListViewItem In mylistview.SelectedItems
        valueArray(i) = Item.Text
        i += 1
    Next
```

To get subitems, use item.subitems(1).text ... subitems(2).text.. etc

Cheers